# Pandas - exclude rows that have wrong format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am logging some data and for some reason i have `@^` in the date column. Is there a way to exclude the rows that are not dates. It may happen that there are undesirable characters in other columns as well.

```
2023/08/22 14:26:11, 1.3337, 1.0915, 1.2119, 1.5757
2023/08/22 14:27:15, 1.3161, 1.2086, 1.2007, 1.5865
2023/08/22 14:28:19, 1.2946, 1.2274, 1.2393, 1.5082
2023/08/22 14:29:23, 1.2868, 1.2155, 1.2886, 1.5413
2023/08/22 14:30:27, 1.3072, 1.2443, 1.3193, 1.5766
@^@^@2023/08/22 14:18:27, 1.5304, 1.4373, 1.4711, 1.7271
2023/08/22 14:19:31, 1.5675, 1.3973, 1.5239, 1.8931
```

Comment: `$ grep -v "@"` springs to mind.

Comment: *'It may happen that there are undesirable characters in other columns as well.'* <- can you be more specific? Without saying what they are and where they may be, how are we to know?

Comment: Rather than delete the rows, why not just remove the garbage characters?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `comment` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

> `comment`: *optional character indicating that the remainder of line should not be parsed. **If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether.** This parameter must be a single character.*

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, comment="@")
```

Or, if you need to keep/fix those kind of rows, you can use :

```
df2 = (
    pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None)
        .replace({0: {r"@\^?": ""}}, regex=True) # 0 being the column's name
)

# if needed
# df2[0] = pd.to_datetime(df2[0], yearfirst=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df1)

                     0       1       2       3       4
0  2023/08/22 14:26:11  1.3337  1.0915  1.2119  1.5757
1  2023/08/22 14:27:15  1.3161  1.2086  1.2007  1.5865
2  2023/08/22 14:28:19  1.2946  1.2274  1.2393  1.5082
3  2023/08/22 14:29:23  1.2868  1.2155  1.2886  1.5413
4  2023/08/22 14:30:27  1.3072  1.2443  1.3193  1.5766
5  2023/08/22 14:19:31  1.5675  1.3973  1.5239  1.8931

print(df2)

                     0       1       2       3       4
0  2023/08/22 14:26:11  1.3337  1.0915  1.2119  1.5757
1  2023/08/22 14:27:15  1.3161  1.2086  1.2007  1.5865
2  2023/08/22 14:28:19  1.2946  1.2274  1.2393  1.5082
3  2023/08/22 14:29:23  1.2868  1.2155  1.2886  1.5413
4  2023/08/22 14:30:27  1.3072  1.2443  1.3193  1.5766
5  2023/08/22 14:18:27  1.5304  1.4373  1.4711  1.7271 # <-- line preseved/fixed
6  2023/08/22 14:19:31  1.5675  1.3973  1.5239  1.8931
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with the parameter `errors='coerce'` to parse the datetime column, then any entries with @ will be converted to `NaT`. The rows with `NaT` can then easily be dropped.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = StringIO("""
2023/08/22 14:26:11, 1.3337, 1.0915, 1.2119, 1.5757
2023/08/22 14:27:15, 1.3161, 1.2086, 1.2007, 1.5865
2023/08/22 14:28:19, 1.2946, 1.2274, 1.2393, 1.5082
2023/08/22 14:29:23, 1.2868, 1.2155, 1.2886, 1.5413
2023/08/22 14:30:27, 1.3072, 1.2443, 1.3193, 1.5766
@^@^@2023/08/22 14:18:27, 1.5304, 1.4373, 1.4711, 1.7271
2023/08/22 14:19:31, 1.5675, 1.3973, 1.5239, 1.8931
""")    
df = pd.read_csv(text, header=None)

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna()

print(df)
```

which gives as print result:

```
                    0       1       2       3       4
0 2023-08-22 14:26:11  1.3337  1.0915  1.2119  1.5757
1 2023-08-22 14:27:15  1.3161  1.2086  1.2007  1.5865
2 2023-08-22 14:28:19  1.2946  1.2274  1.2393  1.5082
3 2023-08-22 14:29:23  1.2868  1.2155  1.2886  1.5413
4 2023-08-22 14:30:27  1.3072  1.2443  1.3193  1.5766
6 2023-08-22 14:19:31  1.5675  1.3973  1.5239  1.8931
```